# how to pull the details together from SQL instance?

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to sort the details of number of DB's present in the SQL instance along with their Recovery model type and the size.?

ex: `name` , `recovery_model_desc` resides under `sys.databases` and `size` from `sys.master_files`. Also `database_id` is the shared column.

How to get the result in together?

Comment: `join` both the tables together

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you not just join `sys.databases` to `sys.master_files` on `database_id`? Or do you not know how to use a `JOIN`, is that your question?

Comment: I need to know on JOIN function at this instance, I have basic idea using JOIN but i couldn't make it here

Comment: I've added some reference material links to my answer below alongside the specific code you can use in this example. I hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` the two tables together on the key field you have correctly identified:

```
SELECT db.*, mf.*
FROM sys.databases db
LEFT JOIN sys.master_files mf ON db.database_id = mf.database_id
```

I suspect that the `LEFT JOIN` could just be `JOIN`/`INNER JOIN` as I don't think there can be records in `sys.databases` without any corresponding records in `sys.master_files`, but I don't know for sure, so stuck with a `LEFT JOIN` for that reason.

If you need some basics around `JOIN`s to get you started with understanding how this works, here are some resources:

- [MSDN Blog: Introduction to Joins](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/07/19/introduction-to-joins/)
- [W3 Schools: SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)
- [SQL Authority: Introduction to JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)
- [Essential SQL: Introduction to Database Joins](http://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-12-introduction-to-database-joins/)

I've also often found [a visual explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) to be a helpful reference at times.